# ToDate() Pig UDF import failing

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to convert time in YYYY-MM-DD format to datetime to do some math with them later.

```
grunt> describe times_target;
times_target: {new_format: chararray,target: chararray}

grunt> dump times_target;
(2015-01-24,negative)
(2015-01-24,negative)
(2015-01-24,negative)
(2015-01-24,negative)
```

This is what I tried, and the error that I got:

```
grunt> C = FOREACH times_target GENERATE ToDate(new_format, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
2015-01-28 13:28:00,074 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve ToDate using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

I registered common.pig.jar and it didn't help. What am I doing wrong? I can convert it to ISO but why wouldn't a simple ToDate work?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what version of Pig are you using?

Comment: Thanks for responding and sorry I left that important piece of info out. I am using 0.10.0 from mid-2012.

Answer (score 1):

ToDate was not added to Pig until 0.11

Comment: yep, you're right. I missed it there. Updating the answer.